# Bind9 completely stops responding to queries

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Due to a massive number of requests on each of the application servers (sending a few thousand api calls each second to a few hundreds domains) I've decided to install Bind9 on each app server as a caching-forwarding only server which would use the "main" recursive DNS we already had. This setup worked quite well for about a year. Since last week (no updates performed last week) Bind9 stops responding to queries. The logs return nothing at all, no crash report as the service is still running, rndc status (or any rndc command for that matter) hangs. I enabled querylog, thinking that maybe something happens and Bind is not receiving the queries. That's not the case, as even after Bind jams, I still see the queries being logged.
Here's the config I'm using:

```
acl goodclients {
        172.16.0.0/21;
        localhost;
};

statistics-channels {
        inet 127.0.0.1 port 8653 allow { 127.0.0.1; };
};

options {
        querylog yes;

        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        max-cache-size 10G;

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { goodclients; };

#        listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };
        listen-on { any; };

#        clients-per-query 100;
#        max-clients-per-query 100;

        clients-per-query 1000;
        max-clients-per-query 1000;
        tcp-clients 1000;
        recursive-clients 5000;

        forwarders {
                172.16.2.200;
        };
        forward only;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { none; };
};
```

Today I've also set

```
logging {
        channel default_file {
                file "/var/cache/bind/named.log" size 100m versions 100 suffix increment;
                severity debug;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };
        category default{ default_file; };
};
```

Also, I've changed

```
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
```

to

```
        dnssec-enable no;
        dnssec-validation no;
```

Hoping that something will come out of this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you see queries in the logfile and nothing else? `rndc status` shouldn't hang. Did you try restarting the service? You are not specifying the OS or bind version. Check the usual culprits (full filesystem and the like)

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for taking time to respond.
Yes, I see the queries and that's it. Restarting the service helps, but it dies again in a matter of hours. The thing is that if I do
`systemctl restart bind9`
hangs for about 3 - 5 minutes then it restarts. If I kill it using 
`kill -9 <pid>`
and then restart , it restarts in a matter of seconds.
The disk's not full (a few hundred GBs free and I'm using 3 - 5% inodes), the load is 20 (40 cores, 128GBs memory). 
The OS used is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Linux kernel 5.4.0-72-generic
Bind version: BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu (Stable Release) <id:d497c32>

Comment: It just died again. With the loglevel set to debug nothing useful is logged. Any ideas?

Comment: Other logs in the system might be useful too. strace the process if nothing else. "The load is 20" was it always like that so high? Maybe bind just does not get any fair share of CPU and hence can not work. Can it do outbound DNS queries? CAn it reach `172.16.2.200`?

Comment: 1. If you let me know what logs you need, I can provide them. I checked them all, nothing was useful.
2. I don't really know how I can strace the process as this issue is not easy to reproduce. Sometimes it happens on 5 servers in an hour, maybe, while at other times it happens at 10 / day.
3. Yes, the load was the same. There are thousand of connections to that server / second. The load did not increase when this issue started, we're also monitoring the number of TCP connections to the server, those didn't increase, memory usage is the same...
4. Yes, it can query 172.16.2.200 at all times

Comment: If anyone hits this, it seems that the 
`statistics-channels {
  inet 127.0.0.1 port 8653 allow { 127.0.0.1; }; 
};`
is to blame. I removed that line from the config last night, all the servers were still running this morning.... I don't know what's going on with it but, at least so far, it looks to be fixed.